# How to check for mutually exclusive method presence in SDK in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

My problem is the following. I have a library that is depending on the SDK. I need to library to work with multiple versions of SDK. So in dependency SDK there is method A(withSuccess:EmptyBlock failure:errorBlock) in older version and method A(withSuccess:SomeObjectBlock failure:errorBlock) in newer version. This clearly means that there cannot be a if respondsToSelector call as the methods are mutually exclusive my library will always fail to compile, since one of the methods are not there. My question is can I somehow achieve that using some reflection via strings or something similar. The solution should preferably be in Swift.

Comment: Is the SDK yours? Or can you access its code? It should have marked it's methods with [`@available`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html) attributes.

Comment: You can write an extension to the class in the SDK that checks when to use old A or new A.

Comment: I cannot alter the SDK. Sorry to not mention that. It is certified binary and cannot be altered.

Comment: That's why I suggested to use an extension.

Comment: How do I do that ? I mean yeah I can use an extension of SDK class, but I need to call either method with empty block or method with object block and compiling that will give me compiler error, since they are not both present at any given time

Comment: Make a new method in your extension that you call from your code where you can pass an empty block or object block (are they the same type?). Inside that method you put your logic and call the method in the SDK passing the correct block.

Comment: Two of the SDK methods are as follows: method A(success:()) in the older version and method A(success:(SomeObject)) in newer version. I cannot call both of them in the code. Meaning I cannot do the simple if (someLogicTodetectSDKVersion == new) then call method A(success:(SomeObject)) else call method A(success:()), because the moment I compile only one of method A will be in the SDK and the compiler fails

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code(a library in this case) is directly dependent on an external dependency(some SDK, that you probably do not own). To solve this problem you need to remove this dependency by making an intermediate Interface to which your code can depend on and to which the SDK can plug-in, essentially reversing the dependency. The interface can choose(preferably at compile time) between a specific implementation that can work with a specific version of the external SDK thus, enabling you to write as many implementations of the interface and supporting many versions of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** saw your comment after I typed this, so probably not useful.

Disclaimer: typed in browser only, not tested in Xcode

Without knowing the types of your blocks, you could try something like this:

```swift
extension SDKClass {
   func MyMethod(_ block: BlockType?) {
      if let block = block {
         // block is not nil so call method A
         self.A(withSuccess:block failure:errorBlock)
      }
      else {
         // block is nil so call method B
         self.B(withSuccess:nil failure:errorBlock)
      }
   }
}
```